# Run terminated thread java android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Terminated Thread Revival](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411509/terminated-thread-revival)

```
 Thread threadWait = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(10000);
                sync = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }               
    };
```

I call this thread here:

```
            threadWait.start();
        while(sync){
        //do something
        }
```

when threadWait finished the state is TERMINATED. How i can start the thread another time? Any idea? THX TO ALL!

SOLUTION:

```
Runnable runWait = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            sync = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
};
```

and..

```
Thread first = new Thread(runWait);
            first.start();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411509/terminated-thread-revival

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How i can start the thread another time?

You can't. Any thread can only be run once. Of course, you can create a new `Thread` with the same `Runnable` if you want, and start that second thread...

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    // Code as before
};
Thread first = new Thread(runnable);
first.start();
... Maybe the first thread dies...
Thread second = new Thread(runnable);
second.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot start the same `Thread` object several times. Just create new `Thread` and start it.